# Retrieve System Default Android Contact Picture

Tags: android, contacts, default, android-contacts

I know this may sound strange, but I want to retrieve the system default contact picture. You know, that icon that's used when there is no picture for the contact. It differs between different versions of Android, but it's generally a blank face, or a grey android, or whatever.

Can I get that image from the system and use it in my app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find them in the drawable folder of the resources that come with the emulator.

`\android-sdk\platforms\android-v#\data\res\drawable\`

Comment: Thanks, I found it in \android-sdk\platforms\android-v#\data\res\drawable-<format>\ic_contact_picture.png

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can get the picture programmatically in app, because that image is private to Phone app of android.

If you want to copy the picture to your folder, it will be present at

```
/packages/apps/Phone/res/drawable-hdpi/picture_unknown.png
```

in AOSP code

Comment: does that mean it is free to use?