# Android: Get dummy icon of a contact

Tags: java, android

In Android: I would like to get dummy icon assign to a contact. I'm able to get if there's any image assign to the contact with contact-id.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: get the dummy image assign to contact in contacts app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this url [Retrieve System Default Android Contact Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224167/retrieve-system-default-android-contact-picture).

I think this image is private to Contacts application and you may get the image from

```
\android-sdk\platforms\android-v#\data\res\drawable\
```

Comment: you are suggesting to copy the image from [\android-sdk\platforms\android-v#\data\res\drawable\] to the res folder of app?

Comment: Yes. I dont think you can get the picture programmatically.

Comment: I will accept your answer though it doesn’t match with my question but provides credible info.