# Default image for contact Android 4.3

Tags: android

I can't seem to find the resource on the device for the default contact image. I was only able to find this `sdk/platforms/android-18/data/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_contact_picture.png`, however once I try using this photo and setting the contact photo in my code using this image (which I've added to `/assets`), the quality does not match the default on the device.

Could there possibly be a URI that has this image on the device already?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224167/retrieve-system-default-android-contact-picture

Answer (score 1):

In order to match different screen resolutions you need to use the MDPD / HDPI / XHDPI versions.

The easiest way is to copy the different versions of the images in the `res/drawable-mdpi`, `res/drawable-hdpi` and `res/drawable-xhdpi` folders of your project, using the same filename, `ic_contact_picture` (you will find them in the same path as you mention, only replacing "xhdpi"). You then refer to the image in your Java code as

```
R.drawable.ic_contact_picture
```

or in XML as

```
android:drawable="@drawable/ic_contact_picture"
```

This way, the system will automatically choose the version which matches your resolution.